# how to use direction service for more than two points on google maps

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I only want to know how to use bearing to calculate the direction for more than two points. all the data is stored in mysql database. i have already used the direction service but it is used only for two points and i want to plot all the points in my database and get the direction on google map for all the points. if anybody knows how to use bearing to get the direction for more than two points please tell me.

here is my code used for direction service:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body onLoad="initialize( )">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:96%;height:400px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService( );
var map;
function initialize( ) {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( );
var GF = new google.maps.LatLng(38.6008, 78.9931 );// Changeable
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
center: GF
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions );
directionsDisplay.setMap( map );
calcRoute( );
}
function calcRoute( ) {
var request = {
origin:"34.7904, 75.8195",// Changeable
destination:"30.6448, 78.9622", // Changeable
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
};
directionsService.route( request, function( response, status ) {
if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK )
directionsDisplay.setDirections( response )
;
} );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to use direction service with mysql database which shows all the points stored in my database and shows the direction in which user is moving.

Comment: If this a question about code you have written, please provide that code.  Are you using the directions service for driving directions or trying to calculate a bearing from one location to another?

Comment: actually i want to plot all my points on map and it will show that the user was gone through this route. Bearing is already stored in my database but i don't know how to use bearing to plot the points and shows the user directions.

Comment: Sounds like you just care about directions (which would make bearing irrelevant). What does your code look like?  Can you provide a simple example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have attached my code now. i want to show the user movements according to his directions. i use simple code to show all the markers but i don't know how to use the direction method with it